# How to represent one variable in terms of others in a system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I have an pretty complex equation set

[image]

But when I clicked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (a.k.a Evaluate Cell), nothing happened.

What should I do?

Comment: Usually it's better to paste the code here than to upload a screenshot, that way we can run it and see what the problem is.  Also, what do you mean nothing happened?  Did the symbol `In[]:=` appear next to your input?  Did you get any output, like `{{}}`?  Also, you seem to be solving all those equations for one variable, and the very first equation is already solved for that variable.

Comment: Are you sure `Ctrl+Enter` should work, shouldn't it be `Shift+Enter`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, `3` equations and more than `10` unknowns, moreover the first equation is just solved with respect to `V0` and it doesn't appear anywhere else to be simplified more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
eqn =
  {vo == r1 + v2/(r1 + 1/(I w + c1)),
   v1 == ((rs + 1/(I w + cs)) v2 + rf + vin)/(rs + rf + 1/(I w + cs)),
   (vin - v2)/(rs + rf + 1/(I w + cs)) == 2 gm v1 + v2/(r1 + 1/(I w + c1))};
```

then

```
Solve[eqn, {vo, v1, v2}]// FullSimplify
```

gives the following solution

[image: solution]